# Updating a boolean value in multithreaded process

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have the following code:

```
public class CheckIfSame implements Runnable {

private int[][] m;
private int[][] mNew;
private int row;
private boolean same;

public CheckIfSame(int[][] m,int[][] mNew,,int row,boolean same) {
    this.m = m;
    this.mNew = mNew;
    this.row = row;
    this.same = same;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mUpd[0].length; i++) {
        if(m[row][i] != mUpd[row][i]) {
            same = false;
        }       
    }

}
```

}

Basically, the idea of this is that I use multi-threading to check row by row, whether the 2 matrices differ by at least 1 element.

I activate these threads through my main class, passing rows to an executor pool.

**However, for some reason, the boolean same does not seem to update to `false`, even if the if condition is satisfied.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiple threads are trying to access that boolean at the same time: a [*race condition*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34550/2148953) while updating the **`same`** variable.

Another possible scenario for non-volatile booleans in multithreaded applications is being affected by compiler optimizations - some threads may never notice the changes on the boolean, as the compiler should assume the value didn't change. As a result, until an specific trigger, such as a *thread state* change, threads may be reading stale/cached data.

You could choose an [**`AtomicBoolean`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html). Use it when you **have multiple threads accessing a boolean variable**. This will guarantee:

- Synchronization.
- Visibility of the updates *(AtomicBoolean uses a volatile int internally).*

For example:

```
public class CheckIfSame implements Runnable 
{
   //...
   private AtomicBoolean same;

   public CheckIfSame(..., AtomicBoolean same) 
   {
    //...
    this.same = same;
   }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < mUpd[0].length; i++) 
         if(m[row][i] != mUpd[row][i]) 
             same.set(false);   //  <--race conditions hate this
    }  
 }
```